# PHP Websockets with Wrench

Tags: php, websocket

I try to set up secure websocket with Wrench.
I created an auto-signed certificate and generated an .pem file. I try the example application "Echo", it seems to contain problem in the code for ssl. Here's my code :

```
require_once 'D:\wamp\www\PrivateChat\lib\SplClassLoader.php';
$classLoader = new SplClassLoader("Wrench", "D:\wamp\www\PrivateChat\lib\\");
$classLoader->register();

use Wrench\BasicServer;

$server = new \Wrench\Server('wss://localhost:12345', array(
    'connection_manager_options' => array(
        'socket_master_options' => array(
            'server_ssl_cert_file' => 'D:\wamp\www\PrivateChat\cert\certificat.pem',
            'server_ssl_passphrase' => 'xavier2014epfctfe',
            'server_ssl_allow_self_signed' => true,
            'server_ssl_verify_peer' => false,
        ),
    )
));

$server->registerApplication('echo', new Wrench\Application\EchoApplication());
$server->run();
```

Client JS :

```
        websocket = new WebSocket("wss://localhost:12345/echo");
        websocket.onopen = function(ev) {
            alert('Connected');
        };
```

Do you know how I can solve that?

Errors:

*PHP Warning:  stream_socket_accept(): failed to create an SSL handle in lib\Wrench\Socket\ServerSocket.php on line 87

*PHP Warning:  socket_last_error() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean gi
ven in lib\Wrench\Socket\ServerSocket.php on line 90

EDIT : The first error i get is for ssl handler when stream_socket_accept try to accept a connection.
I'm thinking i can't use it correctly, can you help me please?